# It is possible to hibernate an LXC container?

Tags: hibernate, lxc, persistence

I know about lxc-freeze and lxc-unfreeze, but as I understand it, these simply pauses the container, similar to sending SIGSTOP and SIGCONT to a process. If I reboot the host, then the containers will cease to exist, right?

I would really like a way to save state to persistent storage so that I could resume them at some later time, even the host is rebooted or something like that. I can achieve exactly what I want using VirtualBox by using the "Save machine state" mechanism, but if I could do it with LXC, it would be completely awesome.

Answer (score 7):

You want [lxc-checkpoint](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/man/lxc-checkpoint.html), which is not yet implemented, at the time of writing (Jun 2014).

> checkpoint the specified container NAME and dumps its state into the file FILE. If the option --pause is specified, the application will be stopped after the checkpoint just before resuming execution. The command lxc-unfreeze will resume its execution.
>
> Actually, this command does not operate. Its description helps to define a CLI api for future Checkpoint / Restart solution